# Реализовать смену UserControl в главном окне WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Каким образом можно в главном окне подсовывать нужный `UserControl` без изменения параметра видимости. К примеру есть окно при запуске отображается `FirstUserControl` потом при каком нибудь событие (например нажатие на кнопку) `FirstUcerControl` отрабатывает (закрывается), и отображается новый `SecondUserControl`.

Comment: `без изменения параметра видимости` - т.е. смена изменением `Visibility` вас не устраивает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет такой вариант не устраивает, так как по сути `SecondUserControl` будет храниться в памяти и т.д. как только отработает `FirstUserControl` его параметры надо сразу же почистить ну или что то в этом вроде.

Comment: Используйте `ContentControl`. В его свойстве `Content` вы можете выставлять нужный вам `UserControl` в любой момент времени. В MVVM  вы просто создаете свойство типа `object`, к которому будете байндить свойство `Content`.

Comment: @John спасибо большое сейчас попробую:))

Answer (score 2):

Для этого используется `DataTemplateSelector`. Я покажу небольшой пример.

Допустим, у меня есть VM-классы `CarVm` и `UserVm`, которые я хочу отображать в одном окне, я набросал такую простую `MainVm`:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    object innerVm;
    public object InnerVm
    {
        get => innerVm;
        set => Set(ref innerVm, value, nameof(InnerVm));
    }

    public DelegateCommand ChangeCommand { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        ChangeCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => InnerVm = (InnerVm is UserVm) ? (object)new CarVm() : (object)new UserVm());
    }
}
```

Тут всё просто, по команде у нас меняется свойство `InnerVm`, причем оно каждый раз будет менять тип.

Займемся разметкой, я в `Grid` добавлю `ContentPresenter` для отображения `InnerVm` и кнопку для вызова команды:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InnerVm}">

    </ContentPresenter>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Change"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Теперь нам для каждого отображаемого типа необходимо реализовать DataTemplate-разметку, я добавлю ее в ресурсы `ContentPresenter`:

```
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
                <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=c:UserVm}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarTemplate">
                <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=c:CarVm}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxSpeed}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
```

Теперь пишем класс-наследник `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var fe = (FrameworkElement)container;
        if (item is UserVm) return fe.FindResource("UserTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        if (item is CarVm) return fe.FindResource("CarTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Создаем экземпляр этого класса в ресурсах `Grid`:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

И подключаем его к нашему `ContentPresenter`: `ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"`

Готово!

[image: шевелится]

Comment: а чем этот подход лучше, чем просто выкинуть старый контрол и засунуть новый в ContentControl?

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю зачем в данном случае использовать селектор - на мой взгляд проще установить `DataType`

Comment: @tym32167, ни чем не лучше, просто как один из вариантов

Comment: @FoggyFinder, хорошо знать несколько способов, в зависимости от ситуации можно использовать тот или иной подход

Comment: ну вот это и хочется понять, когда что лучше использовать

Comment: @tym32167, селектором удобно пользоваться, когда на один и тот же тип могут выдаваться разные шаблоны, например, в зависимости от каких-то других обстоятельств. Или наоборот, один и тот же шаблон на разные типы. В разметке такое не всегда возможно, да и громоздко обычно выходит.

Comment: @tym32167 В случае ContentPresenter по идее не будет нарушаться MVVM. Если просто менять UserControl в Content, то это значит, что VM будет напрямую управлять View, что несколько противоречит паттерну. В Presenter твоя VM будет управлять только другим VM, а вот View будет сама выбирать нужный View в зависимости от типа VM

Comment: @John MVVM может быть нарушен, если менять тем способом, что вы описали. Но это не единственный способ. Для таких вещей делают всякие контент-хелперы, регион-менеджеры, вью-адаптеры. Например, [RegionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.regionmanager(v=pandp.40))

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно где-нибудь посмотреть полностью проект? Спасибо.

Comment: @eusataf, к сожалению, ничего не осталось с тех пор