# Изменение UserControl внутри Border в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется Border, внутри которого должен лежать один из трех UserControl.
Выбор UserControl осуществляется в зависимости от EventType в ViewModel.

Пробовал так:

```
<local:SignalEventView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <local:SignalEventView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EventType}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:SignalEventView.Style>
</local:SignalEventView>
<local:TimeEventView>
    <local:TimeEventView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EventType}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:TimeEventView.Style>
</local:TimeEventView>
```

Но ничего не вышло...
Как реализовать это?

Comment: [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774421/218063) смотрели? Не подходит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP , спасибо, нашел там ответ. Когда смогу отвечать на собственный вопрос обновлю его для потомков.