# Задать Template кодом C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как вот это задать с помощью кода C#, Template ="{StaticResource btTemplate}"

Comment: А какая у вас задача конечная? Зачем так изощряться? Почему не XAML?

Comment: Здесь пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774441/218063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<класс_контролла> <имя_контролла> = new <класс_контролла>()
{
    //всякие присваивания и настройки элементов контролла и наконец:
    Template = Application.Current.FindResource("<имя_шаблона>") as ControlTemplate
};
```